# Cuando hago click sobre un menu las opiocnes se suben con respecto al ancho

Tags: html, css

Cuando hago click sobre un menú desplegable aparece bien el despliegue de las opciones, es decir al borde del marco rojo del menú (Imagen 1). Pero cuando me muevo para seleccionar alguna este (recuadro blanco) se sube quedando un poco arriba. Como se puede corregir esto. Gracias.

[image: Imagen 1]

[image: Imagen 2]

Comment: Debes colocar tu código para poder ayudarte, de lo contrario nos sera imposible.

Comment: El error puede ser por diversos factores, postea el código o [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para ayudarte con mejor precisión.